# '80s kids movie with 3 orbs in a house, and one is evil

Tags: story-identification, movie, b-movies

I really don’t know if it’s from the '80s, but I think so.  It’s about a family that moves in a house and there are three orbs that are trapped there.  One is evil and won’t let the other two leave.  If I’m remembering right, they're mother and son.

Comment: It's been a very long time since I've seen it, but my first thought was the 1986 movie by Disney, [Mr. Boogedy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Boogedy).

Comment: Yes!!! That is it! I have been trying to figure this out for years. Thank you!!

Comment: I've posted this as an answer. If it's correct please accept it so others will know it too.

Comment: @Mal Accepting it works by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Answer (score 4):

Could this be the 1986 Disney movie *[Mr. Boogedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Boogedy)*? I originally thought of *Mr Boogedy* because of the family moving to a new house with three spirits (not appearing as orbs) with one of them being evil and preventing the other two from leaving.

Below is the original TV intro for the movie.

Comment: I remember that movie. "Boogedy Boogedy Boogedy, just kidding!" But why do you think it matches?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots It's been a year, but IIRC I originally thought of *Mr Boogedy* because of the family moving to a new house with three spirits (not appearing as orbs) with one of them being evil and preventing the other two from leaving. I posted this answer due to the OP recently commenting "Yes!!! That is it!", presumably in response to my original comment.

Comment: Got it. Sorry, didn't notice their comment.

Answer (score 3):

This is possibly, *[The Haunted](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102007/)*, a 1991 TV movie.

The plot summary from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Haunted_(1991_film)) identifies three spirits:

> The Smurl family move into their new home on Chase Street only to find that it is plagued with three spirits and a demon. The demon wants to destroy their family and they are constantly desperate until they find the Warren family to get rid of them.

The spirits don't appear as orbs, exactly, but they do appear as uncertain, shadowy blurs on a number of occasions.

The whole thing is on YouTube.